# Systemd user specific service and timer

Tags: scripting, login, systemd

I have installed arch recently and added a few of my own services, for example the `acpi_call` commands and such. Now I want to create a systemd service that runs every 5 minutes and execute a script.

I searched a lot and I found that I must use timers. I got the thing with the timers working, but because my script has to do with a specific user, I want it to run only every 5 minutes when i am logged in as that user.

I tried to put the files in `/etc/systemd/users`, `.config/local/users` and all the possibilities but everytime i want to enable it, it says dbus connection refused.

Can somebody please provide me a way to execute a systemd service every 5 minutes while I am logged in as a specific user?

thanks!

Comment: You need to run the [D-Bus server as a service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#D-Bus) for user sessions...

Comment: I did, i followed the wiki but it didn't work. I keep getting the same dbus connection refused error

Comment: Then you need to look at the output of `systemctl status` for both services to determine what is not working...

Comment: My dbus is running. Checked it with the systemctl status dbus.socket so there is nothing wrong with that. Whenever i place the system services in ~/.config/systemd/user, and i enable it with systemctl --user enable servicename.timer, it just gives the erro message again

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the service and timer files in `.config/systemd/user/` of the user you are targeting.

Log in as that user and enable and start it with: `systemctl --user enable unit_name.timer` etc.